# Excel - Remove Middle Name and replace with first letter

Tags: excel, macros

I have a number of excel Workbooks with multiple sheets of student data.

The Name of the Students is in the format: Mr. Abcd Efgh Ijkl

where: Abcd : First Name; 
Efgh : Middle Name; 
Ijkl : Last Name

I want to be able to run a macros. I am a seasonal user with Excel. But reading on some forum got me the idea of Macros.

The Macro should be able to convert the name into: Mr. Abcd E. Ijkl

where: 
Abcd : First Name
E. : Middle Name, stripped of all alphabets except the first alphabet; The Middle name is of varying lengths though.
Ijkl : Last Name

Please shed light on the same. Or any reference question/answer would also be fine.

Comment: Is it safe to assume there are no suffixes, such as Sr/Jr/III, etc, and that the each part is a single word? For example, no last names like Van der Wiel, or de Mornay, or someone with multiple middle names, such as George Herbert Walker Bush?

Comment: yup @HerbWolfe that would be fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we assume that the middle name is the next-to-the-last component of the full name.

```
Public Function FixName(sIN As String) As String
    Dim st As String

    ary = Split(sIN, " ")
    st = ary(UBound(ary) - 1)
    ary(UBound(ary) - 1) = Left(st, 1) & "."
    FixName = Join(ary, " ")
End Function
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=myfunction(A1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: @user3152887  See my Edit#1... **especially about how and where to install the UDF()** .

Comment: Everyone has middle name?

Comment: @WillBeDeleted  That is what the Poster indicated.